# Can't get a chef cookbook to source .bashrc, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, chef-infra

I wrote a Chef cookbook which configures some servers `.bashrc` file.

Next thing I want to do is to `source` the file to load some aliases that the cookbook adds.

But no matter what I try, the source command doesn't take place or not working and the aliases are missing.

This is the relevant portion of the cookbook:

```
bash 'create_command' do
  user 'ubuntu'
    code <<-EOH
      grep -q "\.isMaster.js" /home/ubuntu/.bashrc || echo "alias isMaster='/usr/bin/mongo localhost:27017 --quiet .isMaster.js'" | tee -a /home/ubuntu/.bashrc
EOH
end

execute "source_bashrc" do
  command "bash -c 'source /home/ubuntu/.bashrc'"
end
```

Here's what I've tried:
1. Adding the source command as a second line of the bash 'create_command' code.

2. Added the second block in the portion.
3. Editing the command line to:

   command 'source /home/ubuntu/.bashrc' #(without the "bash -c")

Also tried adding:

```
script 'source_bashrc' do
interpreter "bash"
code <<-EOH
#!/bin/bash
source /home/ubuntu/.bashrc
EOH
end
```

I've tried some other stuff as well but no matter what I do, the `.bashrc` file is not source'ed.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't how environment variables work. When you use `source` in a shell, that shell process evaluates the file and calls `setenv()` a bunch (and maybe some other things). But that only affects the current process (which again, is `bash`, not `chef-client`) and future child processes. A child process can't modify environment variables in its parent. This is true across all OSes and is unrelated to Chef. So that `source` does work, but it applies only to that bit of script so it effectively does nothing.

Comment: I see. Is there any other way to set aliases using a cookbook then?

Comment: I don't really understand the question, aliases only exist within your shell any way so they aren't even environment variables. What are you trying to do?

Comment: *Wanting* aliases to exist in Chef is probably the root cause here. Generally, use scripts for things which need to work outside of your interactive sessions (and generally prefer functions over aliases for interactive stuff).

Answer (score 0):

It's explained in @coderanger answer. I only can suggest a workaround I found helpful. I created a variable

`my_stuff_home = '/usr/local/share/my_stuff'`

Then I export it to bash_profile for future usage

```
echo 'export MY_STUFF_HOME=' | tr -d '\n' >> #{bash_profile} &&
          echo '#{my_stuff_home}' >> #{bash_profile} &&
          echo 'export PATH=$MY_STUFF_HOME/bin:$PATH' >> #{bash_profile}
```

And further in the same recipe I na use `my_stuff_home` variable again without actually using MY_STUFF_HOME and `source`

Comment: It's not really clear what you are suggesting here. If you put your scripts in `/usr/local/share/my_stuff` instead of define them as aliases, that's probably a good idea per se; but your answer should then explain this in more detail. (I don't see why you need to `export` the variable, or even define this path as a variable in the first place. Perhaps I just failed to guess what you are trying to say.) The tortured `echo`s look like you need to discover `printf`.